# What do you do if you find your stolen bike's frame on ebay?

Tags: frames, theft

I am 85% certain that I see my bike's frame on eBay. It costs almost 2k with all the components and I see the frame on sale for $400 with seat-post and fork only. All my stickers not in the pictures(3) however the frame is the same size and picture only shows the side with no identifiable mark.

The frame itself is rare, not expensive but the brand is not widely sold. And if its sold used, its almost always a complete bike. The manufacturer doesn't sell frame only.

It was stolen, from a bike rack, in open daylight in downtown in big city, I suspect that I forgot to lock it. Lock was on the frame and so was my helmet. I reported the bike stolen on bike index and did file a police report. And posted the bike on local FB groups for stolen bikes.

It is now on sale on ebay, 5 days after about 100 miles away from where I am. Item says local pickup only?

UPDATE: I am now less certain that it is indeed my bike. More like 40%

Comment: Standard procedure is to win the auction, tell the person you’ll pay cash on delivery, and go meet him with the burliest friend you have (or with local PD if they’re willing). The problem is that the you’re not 100% confident it’s yours.

Comment: Unless you have a serial number you cannot prove it is your bike.

Comment: i do have the serial

Comment: Then call the cops and ebay if you have the serial number

Comment: @RoboKaren - only problem with that is if it is not your bike, you end up owning a frame you may not want (Auction is a legally binding contract).

Comment: The absolute first thing I would do is save the web page and every relevant image, to a dated folder.  Also save the seller's info page, as much as you can see.

Comment: This is less a bicycles.SE question and more of a law.SE question.

Comment: @Criggie, there is archive.org for this, just tell the wayback machine to save off that Ebay page.

Comment: "Hey, can you tell me the serial number on that frame?  Some of the earlier ones are not compatible with my other parts, and the serial number has that info... "

Comment: @NH. I tested an ebay auction, and it says "Wayback Machine doesn't have that page archived.  Want to search for all archived pages?"       So maybe, but I wouldn't rely on it.  Better to act in your own interest and spend a moment saving the info locally.  Ebay can also delete auctions too, hence "save it **now**"

Comment: @Criggie, once it shows that message, you have to click the "Save this url in the Wayback Machine" link. It will then archive the page that it wouldn't otherwise have archived.

Comment: @nh this is becoming chat.  Please don't use comments for chat.  I've made the point about saving the images/auction immediately to local disk, so that you have it, and its dated.   I've also pointed out that things vanish from the web, whether it be ebay or any other service.  Whats in your own possession won't vanish.   Done.

Comment: Is this the bike that [went to Guatemala](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/53815/33084)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To determine if the bike is indeed yours, you could contact the seller and ask for more information about the bike and for more pictures in the hope that you'll get one with a visible identifying mark.

You'll need to be careful. If the seller know's it's stolen asking for more information and pictures could tip them off that you are the rightful owner with the intention of retrieving your property.

You should read the [Ebay Stolen Property Policy](https://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/stolen.html) for what to do if you are convinced the bike is in fact yours.

Answer (score -4):

Buy it.

You'll get your bike frame back quickly.

Once you've identified it, you can choose to make a police report, but the chances of a prosecution are probably very low anyway.

Comment: Even if you can't prosecute, if you can prove it's yours, you should just be able to do a paypal chargeback. Paypal is great for screwing over sellers whether or not they deserve it; when they do deserve it, have fun.

Comment: Interesting thought, but I'd much rather the seller/presumed thief/receiver suffered, not reward them with money.

Comment: @R.. paypay will just wash they hands .... If you ask for a refund they will wait for money to move to the destiny and then go and just ask if every thing is correct to the other part. If he say yes say good bay to your money even if it is a scam and seller didn't ever send you the product or didn't did the service or what ever. talking from experience here.

Comment: @kifli: Talk with people who've used paypal as sellers and they'll tell you it doesn't work that way. Paypal almost always errs on the buyer's side.

Comment: @R.. Of course they screw every one but them selfs they dont care it is not their problem... paypay it is a terrible service and it is scary how much extended it is.

I know a guy who got scammed selling the buyer cancelled the bank transfer. He was smarted that me and went right to the police.